# How to pass data from one route to another in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to apache camel. My project is written in camel xml file.

I have a requirement like get the data from file and first check the data is available in DB by calling a GET api and if the data is there then do some change in the data and again call a PUT api for update the data. And if data is not there then just call PUT api which will create a new record.

Below are the code already have and I tried doing something

eqosRoutes.xml

```
<routeContext id="eqosRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<route id="eqosSupplierFilePollerRoute">
    <from
        uri="file://{{eqos.feed.polling.directory}}?fileName={{eqos.feed.supplier.file.name}}&amp;doneFileName={{eqos.feed.supplier.trigger.file.name}}&amp;move=.done&amp;moveFailed=.error&amp;delay={{eqos.feed.polling.interval}}&amp;charset={{eqos.feed.character.encoding}}" />
    <log
        message="EQOS Supplier Feed Poller Route Received a File for processing.."
                        loggingLevel="INFO" />
    <enrich uri="direct:setUserTokenCache" strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" />
    <to uri="direct:processEQOSSupplier" />
</route>

<route id="eqosSupplierProcessRoute1">
    <from uri="direct:processEQOSSupplier"/>

    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="EQOS Supplier Feed Processing Started" />
    <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="false">
        <ref>staxRecordEQOSSupplier</ref>
        <log loggingLevel="INFO"
                         message="EQOS Supplier Feed Processing Started ${body}" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body.supplierId} != null</simple>
                <transform>
                    <method bean="EQOSTransformer" method="transformSupplier" />
                </transform>

                <doTry>
                    <to uri="direct:invokegetPartnerAPI" />

                    <doCatch>
                        <exception>com.hello.tpil.common.exception.AuthenticationException</exception>
                        <handled>
                            <constant>false</constant>
                        </handled>
                        <log loggingLevel="WARN"
                                         message="invokegetPartnerAPI - AuthenticationException..Retrying for.. ${body}" />
                        <to uri="direct:setUserTokenCache" />
                    </doCatch>
                    <doCatch>
                        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                        <handled>
                            <constant>false</constant>
                        </handled>
                        <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                         message="invokegetPartnerAPI - Error invoking API - ${body}" />
                        <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                         message="invokegetPartnerAPI - Exception StackTrace - ${exception}" />
                    </doCatch>
                </doTry>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log loggingLevel="INFO"
                                 message="Not a valid body as supplier ID missing..so ignoring for supplier name ${body.partnerName}" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </split>
    <log message="EQOS Supplier Feed Processing Completed."
                     loggingLevel="INFO" />

</route>

<route id="eqosSupplierProcessRoute">
    <from uri="direct:processEQOSSupplier" />
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="EQOS Supplier Feed Processing Started" />
    <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="false">
        <ref>staxRecordEQOSSupplier</ref>
        <log loggingLevel="INFO"
                         message="EQOS Supplier Feed Processing Started ${body}" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body.supplierId} != null</simple>
                <transform>
                    <method bean="EQOSTransformer" method="transformSupplier" />
                </transform>
                <doTry>
                    <to uri="direct:invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI" />
                    <doCatch>
                        <exception>com.hello.tpil.common.exception.AuthenticationException</exception>
                        <handled>
                            <constant>false</constant>
                        </handled>
                        <log loggingLevel="WARN"
                                         message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - AuthenticationException..Retrying for.. ${body}" />
                        <to uri="direct:setUserTokenCache" />
                    </doCatch>
                    <doCatch>
                        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                        <handled>
                            <constant>false</constant>
                        </handled>
                        <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                         message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - Error invoking API - ${body}" />
                        <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                         message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - Exception StackTrace - ${exception}" />
                    </doCatch>
                </doTry>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log loggingLevel="INFO"
                                 message="Not a valid body as supplier ID missing..so ignoring for supplier name ${body.partnerName}" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </split>
    <log message="EQOS Supplier Feed Processing Completed."
                     loggingLevel="INFO" />
</route>
</routeContext>
```

TradingPartnerRoutes.xml

```
<routeContext id="tradingPartnerRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route id="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI">
    <from uri="direct:invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI" />
    <doTry>
        <enrich uri="direct:getUserTokenCache" strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" />
        <enrich uri="direct:eqosSupplierProcessRoute1" strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>PUT</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="X-Client-Id">
            <constant>{{identity.client.id}}</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - URL >> {{tps.partner.createorreplace.url}}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - Header >> ${headers}" />
        <!--<log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - Body >> ${body}" />-->
        <recipientList parallelProcessing="true">
            <simple>cxfrs://{{tps.partner.createorreplace.url}}</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - Response Code >> ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI - Response body >> ${body}" />
        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${exception.statusCode} != null and ${exception.statusCode} == "401"</simple>
                    <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                                    message="Authentication Exception at Index: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}. Exception: ${exception}" />
                    <throwException ref="authException" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                    message="Processing Failed for Record >>> ${exception.statusCode} ${body}" />
                    <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                    message="Error Processing the Line at Index: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}. Exception: ${exception}" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
<route id="invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI">
    <from uri="direct:invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI" />
    <doTry>
        <enrich uri="direct:getUserTokenCache" strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>PUT</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="X-Client-Id">
            <constant>{{identity.client.id}}</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI - URL >> PUT {{tps.customer.createorreplace.url}}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI - Header >> ${headers}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI - Body >> ${body}" />
        <recipientList parallelProcessing="true">
            <simple>cxfrs://{{tps.customer.createorreplace.url}}</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI - Response Code >> ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                        message="invokeCreateOrReplaceCustomerAPI - Response body >> ${body}" />
        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${exception.statusCode} != null and ${exception.statusCode} == "401"</simple>
                    <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                                    message="Authentication Exception at Index: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}. Exception: ${exception}" />
                    <throwException ref="authException" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                    message="Processing Failed for Record >>> ${exception.statusCode} ${body}" />
                    <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                    message="Error Processing the Line at Index: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}. Exception: ${exception}" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
<route id="invokegetPartnerAPI">
    <from uri="direct:invokegetPartnerAPI" />
    <doTry>
        <enrich uri="direct:getUserTokenCache" strategyRef="aggregationStrategy" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>GET</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <!--<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
                        <constant>application/json</constant>
                    </setHeader>-->
        <setHeader headerName="X-Client-Id">
            <constant>{{identity.client.id}}</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setProperty propertyName="oldBody">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setProperty>

        <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                         message="invokegetPartnerAPI - URL >> {{tps.partner.get.url}}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                         message="invokegetPartnerAPI - Header >> ${headers}" />
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                         message="invokegetPartnerAPI - Body >> ${body}" />
        <recipientList parallelProcessing="true">
            <simple>cxfrs://{{tps.partner.get.url}}?sourceId=52000013&amp;sourceName=EQOS</simple>
        </recipientList>
        <when>
            <simple>${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} == "200"</simple>
            <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                             message="Old Data >> ${exchangeProperty[oldBody]}" />
            <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                             message="invokegetPartnerAPI - Response Code >> ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}" />
            <to uri="direct:invokeCreateOrReplacePartnerAPI" />
        </when>

        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${exception.statusCode} != null and ${exception.statusCode} == "401"</simple>
                    <log loggingLevel="DEBUG"
                                     message="Authentication Exception at Index: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}. Exception: ${exception}" />
                    <throwException ref="authException" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                     message="Processing Failed for Record >>> ${exception.statusCode} ${body}" />
                    <log loggingLevel="ERROR"
                                     message="Error Processing the Line at Index: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}. Exception: ${exception}" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
</routeContext>
```

I am able to call the GET api to check the data is there or not. But after that I have to pass the data to the createOrReplacePartnerAPI to call the PUT api for the updation.

Again I don't want the GET api response other than just checking the availablity of the data.

And One more problem I am facing like I need suplierId to be dynamically add into the URI for the GET url but I couldn't able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my comments below :

I am able to call the GET api to check the data is there or not. But after that I have to pass the data to the createOrReplacePartnerAPI to call the PUT api for the updation.

***[Ankit]: When you call get api than exchange body will replace with response and your data from file will replace. If you want file (split data) after receiving response of get API, you need to store body into exchange properties before sending the request of get call and you can retrieve after get api call.***

Again I don't want the GET api response other than just checking the availablity of the data.
***[Ankit]: You can replace get response body with original file data, which you set in above step.***

And One more problem I am facing like I need suplierId to be dynamically add into the URI for the GET url but I couldn't able to do that.
**[Ankit]: You should create cxfrs endpoint and set http path dynamically like below**

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath">
<simple>/address/comune/${header.id}</simple>
</setHeader>
```